# SwiftyJSON Result to Coredata?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, alamofire, swifty-json

I want to send my swiftyJson results to coredata to be saved.

I have managed to get an array of arrays with my key and details, but im not sure how to correctly pass them into matching entities?

Here is my code:

```
    open func getData() {
    Alamofire.request("http://demomedia.co.uk/files/contacts.json").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if ((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyValue = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

            if let resData = swiftyValue[].arrayObject {
                self.result = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
            }
            // if values passed and formatted...
            if self.result.count > 0 {
                // for each contact result
                for contact in self.result {
                    print(contact)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is an example print:

```
["surname": Peters, "firstname": Julia, "email": jpeters@email.com, "phoneNumber": 07865543432, "createdAt": 1501170757, "address": 66 New Street, "updatedAt": 1501170762, "title": Miss]
```

I have an object that matches these property names, how do i pass it into them and save?

UPDATED CODE:

```
   open func getData() {
    Alamofire.request("http://demomedia.co.uk/files/contacts.json").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if ((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let value = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

            if let resData = value[].arrayObject {
                self.result = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
            }
            // if values passed and formatted...
                for contact in self.result {
                    let newContact = Contact()
                    newContact.surname = contact["surname"] as? String
                    newContact.firstname = contact["firstname"] as? String
                    newContact.email = contact["email"] as? String
                    newContact.phoneNumber = (contact["phoneNumber"] as? Int64)!
                    newContact.createdAt = (contact["createdAt"] as? Int64)!
                    newContact.address = contact["address"] as? String
                    newContact.createdAt = (contact["updatedAt"] as? Int64)!
                    newContact.title = contact["title"] as? String

                    do {
                        try self.context.save()
                    } catch {
                        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to extract the values by the keys of each `contact` for example `let surname = contact["surname"] as? String`. After extracting all values create a record of the entity, assign the values to the attributes and finally save the context. By the way: Your code looks very *objective-cish*.

Comment: how do i reduce it? sorry im just trying to get it working so not focused on code volume, and i work in objc all day!

Comment: Please read the first chapter "The Basics" in the Swift Language Guide especially about optional bindings. It's not a question of code volume, it's a question of code efficiency. For example don't check for `nil`, optional bind a variable. And you don't need the check `self.result.count > 0` (not even in ObjC). If the array is empty the loop will be skipped. And in Swift there is an easier (and better readable) syntax for `array.count == 0` : `array.isEmpty`

Comment: I have updated my OP with the new func, however i crash as soon as i attempt to map, have i made a mistake? there are no errors, i seem to get CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Contact'

Comment: You have to use `NSManagedObject.init(entity:insertInto` or one of the convenience initializers. The context must be involved and the entity description.

Comment: got it, out of interest for the entity parameter, why isnt that the name of my entity? e.g. Contact ?

Comment: In Swift 3 Apple has added a convenience class initializer method which infers the entity description.

Comment: what I mean is id i put Contact as the entity description it throws an error?

Comment: `entityName` is supposed to be a string `"Contact"` not the type `Contact`

Comment: i thought that but i get: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSEntityDescription'

Comment: My bad, use the more contemporary class initializer `Contact.insertNewObject(forEntityName:"Contact" into: context`). `context` is the `NSManagedObjectContext` instance.

Comment: not sure thats right either, Contact doesnt have that property to use... just the init

Comment: Then use `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName:"Contact" into: context)` or does `Contact(context: context)` work, too?

Comment: the Contact(context) seems ok but every time i run i get this crash now [error] error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) in my persistent container app delegate func.. i set it like this     let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

Comment: Please read the documentation how to properly setup the Core Data stack. Or create a new document with `Core Data` check box checked to get the basic implementation of the Core data stack.

Comment: I do and i have...thats why its an odd issue